# Cannot fetch posts with certain "product_cat". WP_Query is empty

Tags: wordpress

I want to set attributes for woocommerce products in certain product category. The query, however, doesn't seem to work.

I've placed the following code into functions.php of my child-theme.
Tried replacing slug by term_id, tried adding 'relation', just in case, tried to set the slug explicitly instead of variable, but still no luck.
UPD: wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query don't work either.

```
function wccategory_set_attributes($categoryslug, $attributes) {
    $pquery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $categoryslug,
            ),
        ),
    ));

    if( $pquery->have_posts() ) {
        while ($pquery->have_posts()) : $pquery->the_post();
            foreach ($attributes as $name => $value) {
                wp_set_object_terms( $postid, $value, $name, false );
                $product_attributes[$i] = array (
                    'name' => htmlspecialchars( stripslashes( $name ) ),
                    'value' => $value,
                    'is_visible' => 1,
                    'is_taxonomy' => 0
                );
                $i++;
            }
            update_post_meta( $postid,'_product_attributes', $product_attributes); 
        endwhile;
    }
}
wccategory_set_attributes('theslug', array ( 'pa_length' => '', 'pa_width' => '', 'pa_type' => ''));
```

$pquery->have_posts() returns nothing. The posts are present, though. Once I remove 'tax_query' from arguments, all works. I assume, that there is some error in 'tax_query'. I looked many other examples, it looks fine, but it seems I'm missing something.

Comment: Try asking on the Wordpress-dedicated Stack Exchange site

Comment: Thanks for information. Didn't know there was one. Does that mean I should delete that question from here?

Comment: Now that you got a response it's fine, let it be

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using get_posts() instead?  If you're simply trying to retrieve a post count the full query may not be necessary, and get_posts returns an array on its own.

Also, rather than trying to work with the returned items outside the function, if the only thing you are returning is the post count, just returning the count?  Lastly, post_count is different from found_posts.  If you have a posts per page set, your post_count will always max out at that number, found_posts will provide all posts that were found in that query.

```
 function get_cat_products_by_slug($category) {

  $products = get_posts(
     array(
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_type' => 'product',
       'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $category->slug,
           )
       )
    )
 );

 $number_of_posts = $products->found_posts;

 return $number_of_posts;

};

$p_query = get_cat_products_by_slug($category);
echo $p_query;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I, however, do not simply trying to retrieve a post count, I've edited the post to reflect what I am trying to achieve.